# How can you dynamically alter blogger content with jquery?

Tags: jquery, templates, dynamic, blogger, alter

```
$('.body-fauxcolumns').load('http://zazzlewidgets.blogspot.com/p/about-me.html');
```

I was experimenting with jquery and blogger and noticed that I can't change the content dynamically through manipulation functions.

Am I doing something wrong? The code was placed into the header.

How can you dynamically alter blogger content with jquery?

Comment: is the page calling `$('.body-fauxcolumns').load()` in `http://zazzlewidgets.blogspot.com` also?

Comment: yes it is, no matter what manipulator or class I use, I can't insert html or load html dynamically for some reason. I can modify attributes of classes though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blogger doesn't allow any AJAX functionality, and limits other JS/JQuery functions as well.

Wrapping your JS in CDATA tags seems to help, but some functions just won't go.